# unable to load images in the products folder

Tags: laravel-8

I have files stored inside the path public_html/storage/app/public/images/products
when I try to load them using `{{asset('storage/images/products/1625469809_default.png')}}` I get a file not found error at the same time I have files inside /storage/app/public/images which if I load using `{{asset('storage/images/default.png')}}` get loaded correctly, what could be the issue with my code? Note that the folder permission is 755 for all folders and 644 for all files

Comment: asset function look into public folder and you are searching in storage folder have you link public with storage folder?

Comment: Yes that is why it is working for the in the second case ```{{asset('storage/images/default.png')}}```